# How to use Boost MPL to have several return points in a function?

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, return, boost-mpl

Consider the following code:

```
struct Param {};
struct Base {
        virtual char f(Param const &) const = 0;
};
struct A : Base {
        explicit A(Param const &) {}
        virtual char f(Param const &) const {return 'A';}
};
struct B : Base {
        explicit B(Param const &) {}
        virtual char f(Param const &) const {return 'B';}
};
struct C : Base {
        explicit C(Param const &) {}
        virtual char f(Param const &) const {return 'C';}
};

char my_function(Param const & param, Base const & base)
{
        if(A const * const p = dynamic_cast<A const *>(&base)) {
                return p->f(param);
        }
        if(B const * const p = dynamic_cast<B const *>(&base)) {
                return p->f(param);
        }
        if(C const * const p = dynamic_cast<C const *>(&base)) {
                return p->f(param);
        }
        return '0';
}
```

Then if I write

```
Param x, y;
std::cout << my_function(x, B(y)) << std::endl;
```

it outputs `B`.

My goal is to change the implementation of `my_function` so that it can support a set of subtypes of `Base` defined at compile-time. Here I have hand-written the expanded code I would obtain for the set of types `{A, B, C}`.
I would like to templatize `my_function` with a set of types, and call it this way:

```
std::cout << my_function<boost::mpl::set<A, B, C> >(x, B(y)) << std::endl;
```

outputting `B`, or, for instance:

```
std::cout << my_function<boost::mpl::set<A, C> >(x, B(y)) << std::endl;
```

outputting `0`.

I don't know which MPL construct to use to achieve this result.

I initially thought a call to `find_if` could allow to find the first type in the set to which `base` can be dynamic_casted, but in fact this algorithm, like most MPL algorithms, produces its result statically so it obviously can't be used with a runtime parameter (`base`).

The only MPL algorithm that is categorized "runtime" is `for_each`, but I don't manage to figure out how to use it to produce the same effect as my multiple return statements (and I even don't know whether it is possible).
Thanks to any MPL-speaker who could help me.

PS: Don't tell me I should avoid dynamic casts or I could simply have

```
char my_function(Param const & param, Base const & base) {return base.f(param);}
```

I have simplified the code sample compared with my real-life problem and I cannot change the existing design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
struct functor
{
  public:
  functor(Param const & param, Base const & base)
  : param_(param),
    base_(base),
    found_(false)
  {
  }

  template<typename Child>
  void operator()(Child*)
  {
    if (!found_)
    {
      if(Child const * const p = dynamic_cast<Child const *>(&base_))
      {
        value_ = p->f(param_);
        found_ = true;
      }
    }
  }

  char get_value()
  {
     return value_;
  }

  private:
  Param const & param_;
  Base const & base_;
  bool found_;
  char value_;
};

template <typename ...Types>
char my_function(Param const & param, Base const & base)
{
  typedef boost::mpl::vector<Types...>::type children;

  functor f(param, base);

  boost::mpl::for_each<children>(std::ref(f));

  return f.get_value();
}

int main()
{
  Param x, y;
  std::cout << my_function<A*, B*, C*>(x, B(y)) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The drawback of your solution is that the entire type list is traversed everytime, but it shows well how to use MPL for_each. Meanwhile, I have found a solution (without using MPL algorithms) that I have posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I have found.

```
namespace detail {

template <typename First, typename Last>
struct my_function_impl {
        static char apply(Param const & param, Base const & base)
        {
                BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_NOT((boost::is_same<First, Last>));
                typedef typename boost::mpl::deref<First>::type Child;
                BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((boost::is_base_of<Base, Child>));
                if(Child const * const p = dynamic_cast<Child const *>(&base)) {
                        return p->f(param);
                }
                typedef typename boost::mpl::next<First>::type Next;
                return my_function_impl<Next, Last>::apply(param, base);
        }
};

template <typename It>
struct my_function_impl<It, It> {
        static char apply(Param const &, Base const &)
        {
                return '0';
        }
};

} // namespace detail

template <typename ContainerOfTypes>
char my_function(Param const & param, Base const & base)
{
        typedef typename boost::mpl::begin<ContainerOfTypes>::type Begin;
        typedef typename boost::mpl::end<ContainerOfTypes>::type End;
        return detail::my_function_impl<Begin, End>::apply(param, base);
}
```

And the call:

```
std::cout << my_function<boost::mpl::set<A, B, so::Base> >(x, C(y)) << std::endl;
```

Any simplification or improvement suggestion is welcome.